# How to create an array to hold the values of several automatically generated checkboxes in Tk Tcl

Tags: arrays, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a list of objects of unknown length, I want to create 2 lists of checkboxes, in each list a checkbox for each line of the list. I also need to be able to get to the checkboxes and check their value.

Since I didn't find a way to get the value of a checkbox from its path, I wanted to create a global array that will hold the variables for the check boxes, and tried the fallowing:

```
    global cb
    set i 0
    foreach port $ports {
    set to_cb    [checkbutton $to.cb_to_$i     -variable [list $cb(to$i)]   -text $port -command [list __sp_from_to_changed $from $to]]
    set from_cb  [checkbutton $from.cb_from_$i -variable [list $cb(from$i)] -text $port -command [list __sp_from_to_changed $from $to]]

    grid $to_cb   -row [expr $i + 2] -sticky nsew
    grid $from_cb -row [expr $i + 2] -sticky nsew
    incr i
```

When I source it  get the error `can't read "cb(to0)": no such variable`, how can I assign a variable inside an array for a check box, or better yet, is there a way to get the current value directly from the checkbox without using intermediate variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkbuttons always need to be bound to a variable (there is a default, but you don't want to use that). What you need to do is to generate the *name* of a variable that is unique for each checkbutton; an array element is an *excellent* choice here.

So what's the problem in your code? It's simply that you're trying to dereference the variables by putting a `$` in front of them; unlike some other languages, Tcl *always* uses the `$` to mean “read this variable” (except in regular expressions). You also don't need to wrap the variable name in `list`; that would only be useful if you putting it into a generated script. Instead, you need lines like this:

```
set to_cb    [checkbutton $to.cb_to_$i     -variable cb(to$i)   -text $port \
        -command [list __sp_from_to_changed to $i]]
set from_cb  [checkbutton $from.cb_from_$i -variable cb(from$i) -text $port \
        -command [list __sp_from_to_changed from $i]]
```

The changes here are:

- Removed the extra generated complexity from the `-variable` option's value; a bare array element name is good enough.
- Updated the arguments to `__sp_from_to_changed` so that they say what has actually been modified (the first argument is now `to` or `from`, and the second is the index; from that, you should be able to construct all the element names you need quite trivially).
- Added a backslash to those long lines so I could break them up for readability. :-)